# XSLTApplyError: xsl:comment : '--' or ending '-' not allowed in comment

Tags: plone, diazo

I am really new to plone and diazo so forgive me if the answer to question is too obvious.

I was asked to create a diazo theme for a website running on plone. Right now i'm at a state where i where i think the theme is reasonably complete(without rules) and i uploded it via .zip to the plone planing to create the rules in plones rules editor. Made a handful of them and hit the preview button to see whether what i am doing is even repotely going into the right direction but hat it showed was this error.

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module plone.app.theming.browser.mapper, line 245, in getFrame
  Module lxml.etree, line 567, in lxml.etree.XSLT.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:124426)
XSLTApplyError: xsl:comment : '--' or ending '-' not allowed in comment
```

After spending quiet some time with a well known search engine i'm still uncertain if that is a mistake i made in the rules.xml or something the websites admin has to look at.

Any and all help will be appreciated.

**Edit version information:**

```
Plone 4.3 (4305)
CMF 2.2.7
Zope 2.13.19
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 4 2013, 09:04:32) [GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)]
PIL 1.7.8 (Pillow)
```

**Edit rules so far**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules
    xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo"
    xmlns:css="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo/css"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- Apply the following rules to standard Plone pages -->
    <rules css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper">

        <theme href="theme.html" />

        <!-- Replace title with Plone's page title  -->
        <replace css:theme="html head title" css:content="html head title" />

        <!-- Copy base tag and script tags from Plone -->
        <after css:theme-children="html head" css:content="html head base" />
        <after css:theme-children="html head" css:content="html head script" />

        <!-- Insert your own rules here -->

        <!-- Replace logo with Plone's logo  -->
        <replace css:theme-children="a#brand img" css:content-children="a#portal-logo img"/>

        <!-- Replace top navigation with Plone's top navigation  -->
        <replace css:theme-children="navbar" css:content-children="ul#portal-globalnav"/>

        <!-- Replace search with Plone's search  -->
        <replace css:theme-children="input.search-query" css:content-children="input#searchGadget"/>

        <!-- Replace top navigation with Plone's top navigation  -->
        <replace css:theme-children="documentDescription" css:content-children="documentDescription"/>


    </rules>

</rules>
```

I didn't create that file myself. It was automatically created by plone upon uploading the .zip without a rules.xml in it. The four(that's how far I got until I first stumbled over the error) rules were created by plones editor.
At first I thought i messed up the comments somehow, seeing that is states "--" and "-" in the error message, but i couldn't find where and DW didn't point out any syntac errors either when opening the file in there.

**Edit Solution:**

Typo found in the theme.html . One comment ended on "->" instead of "-->" which i never new works for html in the first place.

Comment: It sounds like a syntax error in your rules file. Perhaps you could share what you've written so far?

Comment: Remember that your theme must also validate as XML. So, check it, too.

Comment: @SteveM Can't believe I missed a typo in the .html that DW didn't complain about. Never even thought of looking there since the theme alone worked perfectly fine. Even tho it is slightly embarrassing thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

There's some badly formed XML somewhere. It doesn't appear to be in your rules file. Check the theme file.

Every part of the Diazo processing is done with XML and XSLT processors that depend on the input being well-formed XML (or XSLT). That's just as true of the theme and content as of the rules file.

Content coming from Plone should be good XML (the HTML subset). Your rules file looks OK. That leaves the theme file as a candidate for the problem source.

Comment: As i edited in allready, I found the faulty comment in the theme.html
It came from some comment ending on "->" instead of "-->". Didn't know that works for html with only 1 - so i didn't look there in the beginning.
Still thanks for the effort.